[Python][Pandas] Filter dataframe based on column value
I have an excel, which I then need to convert into a dataframe and then further elaborate.
I need to apply the following logic, but let's define a few things
A parent node is one that starts with either WP or CH in the column "Codice" but has never a "."
Each parent node has children nodes, in the format PARENT_NODE + ".A" + number
If a parent has the value "% di completamento" set to 100%, filter the parent + children
Otherwise save into a new df the remaining parent nodes (those who are not 100%).
Code below never works correctly. Picks up stuff that is 100% complete
[..] some code to load excel into a df (named df)
# Identify parent nodes (those that don't have a '.' in 'Codice' and do not start with 'PRO')
df['is_parent'] = ~df['Codice'].str.contains('\.', na=False) & ~df['Codice'].str.startswith('PRO', na=False)

# Identify parent nodes that are not 100% complete
incomplete_parents = df.loc[df['is_parent'] & ((df['% di completamento'] != 100)| (df['% di completamento'] != 1.00)), 'Codice']

# We want to keep rows that are children of non-complete parents or are parents themselves
# Note: It's important to ensure the 'Codice' column doesn't have NaN values for this operation
df['keep'] = df['Codice'].isin(incomplete_parents) | df['Codice'].str.contains(r'\.', na=False)

# Apply the filter to the DataFrame to keep desired rows
filtered_df = df[df['keep']].copy()

# Dropping the helper columns
filtered_df.drop(columns=['is_parent', 'keep'], inplace=True)

# Now let's display the first few rows of the dataframe to verify the output
# print (filtered_df)

columns_to_save = [
            'ID',
            'Codice',
            'Nome dell\'attività',
            'Effort stimato',
            'Inizio',
            'Fine',
            'Durata',
            'Effort consuntivato + Effort Stimato mancante', # Assuming this is the correct column name
            'Diff. Effort',
            '% di completamento',
            'Effort completato'
        ]

filtered_df = filtered_df[columns_to_save].dropna()

# Now filtered_df will only include parent projects that are not 100% complete and all their child tasks
print(filtered_df)  



If you go step-by-step where does it start failing ? Your is_parent filter works ? Then does the incomplete work too ?

From your post it's hard to fully understand what you are trying to do but here is a small code I hope will help.
Just note a few useful things:

You have to make sure your input data is clean or clean it in python
You can combine filters for clarity

test.csv:
codice,% comp.
PRO220287-d,87
WP2,81%
WP2.A3,100
WP2.A4,80
WP12,100
WP12.A13,100%
WP12.A14,100
WP12.A15,100
WP12.A16,100
M18,100
WP19,58
WP19.A20,100
WP19.A21,100
WP19.A22,65
WP19.A23,0
WP19.A24,50

And some code in a notebook:
import pandas as pd

# careful here, you have to make sure that your '%' column is a float, otherwise you will have to convert it
# also make sure excel is not setting it as a [0,1] percentage or update code accordingly
df = pd.read_csv('data/test.csv')
df['% comp.'] = df['% comp.'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float)

# list of criterias, I voluntarily separated them for clarity
parent_criteria = ((df['codice'].str.startswith('WP')) | (df['codice'].str.startswith('CH'))) & (~df['codice'].str.contains('\.'))
incomplete_criteria = df['% comp.'] != 100

# I am very verbose here so you understand what i actually try to filter
incomplete_parents_codices = df.loc[parent_criteria & incomplete_criteria, 'codice']

child_of_incomplete_parents_criteria = df['codice'].str.split('.').str[0].isin(incomplete_parents_codices)
incomplete_child_of_incomplete_parents_criteria = child_of_incomplete_parents_criteria & incomplete_criteria

# will display output in dataframe
df[incomplete_child_of_incomplete_parents_criteria]

Output:

